# AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'length' Не могу понять, как исправить ошибку

Tags: python

Ошибка возникает в этой строке self.length += 1

```
class Node:
    def init(self, value=None, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next
class LinkedList:
    def init(self):
        self.first = None
        self.last = None
        self.length = 0
    def str(self):
        if self.first != None:
            current = self.first
            out = 'LinkedList [\n' + str(current.value) + '\n'
            while current.next != None:
                current = current.next
                out += str(current.value) + '\n'
            return out + ']'
        return 'LinkedList []'

    def clear(self):
        self.init()

#добавление элементов в конец
    def add(self, x):
        a = timeit.default_timer()
        self.length += 1
        if self.first == None:
            # self.first и self.last будут указывать на одну область памяти
            self.last = self.first = Node(x, None)
        else:
            # здесь, уже на разные, т.к. произошло присваивание
            self.last.next = self.last = Node(x, None)
            print(timeit.default_timer() - a)


L = LinkedList()
L.add(1)

print(L)
L.add(15)
print(L)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `__init__` должен иметь именно такое имя - с двойными подчёркиваниями в начале и в конце. Только при таком написании он будет автоматически срабатывать при создании объекта.

У вас же написано просто `init` - такой метод не будет срабатывать автоматически, и если вы не запустите его явно, то он никогда и не выполнится.

Поэтому все атрибуты, которые в нём создаётся, не будут созданы, и у объекта не будет атрибута `.length`